# Select Bottom 30% of Rows by Group in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I need to isolate the last 30% of row records for each group (`ParentID`). eg `ID, ParentID, Value`

Each group may have a different number of row records. In one case it maybe 30, so only the last 10 rows need to be isolated by the select query based on `ID DESC`.

By simply using sort `ID DESC` and selecting Top 30% does not work. The result may yield the last 30% based on group but also stops after 30% of the total rows have been interrogated.

Essentially it needs to do ParentID = 1, Get its last 30% rows then iterate  to ParentID = 2.....until the table is completely processed

The following SQL works to isolate the records based on group (ie RowNumber 1). In reality this needs to be the last 30% of records based on that ParentID reading from the LAST unique record backwards.

*Query that Fails to Get All Data*

```
SELECT TOP (30) PERCENT ID, ParentID, Value
FROM dbo.MyData 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Query that isolates the ParentIDs but does NOT contain the "get last 30%" logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ID, ParentID, Value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ParentID] ORDER BY [ID] DESC) AS [ROW NUMBER]
     FROM dbo.MyData) Group
WHERE Group.[ROW NUMBER] = 1
ORDER BY Group.ID DESC
```

Instead of row number it should be 30% of records. Based on the following sample table this should yield 5 Rows for ParentID = 1, 4 Rows for ParentID =2 , 3 Rows for ParentID = 3 and 2 Rows for ParentID =4

Sample data table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyData]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [float] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyData] ON 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyData] ([ID], [ParentID], [Value]) 
VALUES (1, 1, 25), (2, 1, 24), (3, 1, 24), (4, 1, 24),
       (5, 1, 22), (6, 1, 20), (7, 1, 24), (8, 1, 23),
       (9, 1, 23), (10, 1, 22), (11, 1, 21), (12, 1, 21),
       (13, 1, 23), (14, 1, 23), (15, 1, 20), (16, 2, 24),
       (17, 2, 22), (18, 2, 24), (19, 2, 20), (20, 2, 21),
       (21, 2, 25), (22, 2, 22), (23, 2, 23), (24, 2, 23),
       (25, 2, 22), (26, 2, 25), (27, 2, 20), (28, 3, 21), 
       (29, 3, 21), (30, 3, 20), (31, 3, 25), (32, 3, 21), 
       (33, 3, 25), (34, 3, 24), (35, 3, 25), (36, 3, 24),
       (37, 4, 21), (38, 4, 20), (39, 4, 21), (40, 4, 21),
       (41, 4, 21), (42, 4, 21)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyData] OFF
GO
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do I think:-

```
WITH RecordCount AS (
    SELECT ParentID, ROUND(COUNT(1)*.3, 0) RecordCount -- To be selected
    FROM MyData
    GROUP BY ParentID
), SortedRecords AS (
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY ID DESC) RowIndex
    FROM MyData
)
SELECT d.*
FROM MyData d
    JOIN SortedRecords sr ON d.ID = sr.ID
    JOIN RecordCount rc ON d.ParentID = rc.ParentID AND sr.RowIndex <= rc.RecordCount;
```

Comment: Did a small correction by using ROUND instead of CAST. Hope you notice.

Comment: Hello Chamika, Thankyou for that perfect and timely response. The query now selects fine.  You have achieved the exact outcome I needed. And yes the round plays an important role here, especially when rows are not divisible by 3. difference